# Checkbox Toggle for Multiple GroundOverlays

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, checkbox

What am I missing here? I have been staring at this thing for almost 3 days now, and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I have tried countless examples from various parts of the web, and the documentation isnt making much sense - but then again, letters are starting to run together. Any pointers would be helpful!

The below is what I amy trying to get to work. I have two groundoverlay images, with two checkboxes. What I would like to have happen is if the box is checked, the overlay shows. If the box is unchecked, the overlay goes away. Simple right?

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="controls">
<input name="ckc1" onclick="showcov(rmap1,ckc1);" type="checkbox" checked="true">White Tanks</input>
<input name="ckc2" onclick="showcov(rmap2,ckc2);" type="checkbox" checked="true">Scottsdale</input>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var map;
var rmap1,mk1,ckc1;
var rmap2,mk2,ckc2;
function initialize() {
var coord = new google.maps.LatLng( 33.5783309936523,-112.573112487793);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
      center: {lat: 33.5783309936523, lng:-112.573112487793},
      zoom: 8
    });
//White Tanks   
var boundaries1 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng( 32.22935,-114.1923),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 34.92731,-110.9539));
rmap1 =new google.maps.GroundOverlay("RM77B714BB9248_1.png", boundaries1);  
rmap1.setMap(map);
mk1 =new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng( 33.57832983,-112.57310897),map:map,title:'462.550 Mhz at 50 Watts',draggable:false,zIndex:1});
//Scottsdale
var boundaries2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng( 32.36672,-113.4623), 
    new google.maps.LatLng( 35.06469,-110.2188));
rmap2 =new google.maps.GroundOverlay("RM77B714BB9248_4.png", boundaries2);
rmap2.setMap(map);
mk2 =new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng( 33.715703,-111.840549),map:map,title:'462.600 Mhz at 20 Watts',draggable:false,zIndex:1});
}
//Checkbox Function
function showcov(m,v){if(v.checked) m.setMap(map); else m.setMap(null);}
</script>
</body>
```

The one below works just fine - but it's only one layer. I'm not sure what I am missing, but I'm sure is something simple as I have little experience with JS and mapping in this fashion.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var rmap1,mk1;
function initialize() {
var coord = new google.maps.LatLng( 33.7157020568848,-111.840545654297);
var myOptions = {zoom:  7,center: coord, mapTypeId: 
google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions );
var boundaries1 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng( 32.36672,-113.4623), new google.maps.LatLng( 35.06469,-110.2188));
rmap1 =new google.maps.GroundOverlay("RM77B714BB9248_4.png", boundaries1);
rmap1.setMap(map);
mk1 =new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng( 33.715703,-111.840549),map:map,draggable:false,zIndex:1});
rmap1.setMap(map);
 }
function showcov(m,v){if(v.checked) m.setMap(map); else m.setMap(null);}
</script></head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:80%"></div>
<div style="width:100%;height:10%">
<table width="100%"><tr><th colspan="2">Scottsdale 450 MHz**</th></tr><tr>    <td bgcolor="#E0E0E0" colspan="2"><form name="form2">
<input type="checkbox" name="ckc1" checked="true"     onclick="showcov(rmap1,ckc1);">Scottsdale 450 MHz**</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="ckm1" checked="true"     onclick="showcov(mk1,ckm1);">Scottsdale</input>
</form></td></tr></table></div></body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined`.  you need to pass a reference to the checkbox into the function (`this` works or remove the declaration of the javascript variable so the automatically created reference to the HTML element can be used, as you did in your "working" example).

```
var rmap1,mk1; // ckc1;
var rmap2,mk2; // ckc2;

<input id="ckc1" onclick="showcov(rmap1,ckc1);" type="checkbox" checked="true" />White Tanks
<input id="ckc2" onclick="showcov(rmap2,ckc2);" type="checkbox" checked="true" />Scottsdale
```

2. Your `map` variable (at least the version that is initialized) is local to the `initialize` function, remove the `var` before it to initialize the global version (which is the scope in which HTML click listeners run), the same as you do in your "working" version of the code.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
var coord = new google.maps.LatLng( 33.5783309936523,-112.573112487793);
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
      center: {lat: 33.5783309936523, lng:-112.573112487793},
      zoom: 8
    });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1vjmcxus/2/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="controls">
  <input id="ckc1" onclick="showcov(rmap1,ckc1);" type="checkbox" checked="true" />White Tanks
  <input id="ckc2" onclick="showcov(rmap2,ckc2);" type="checkbox" checked="true" />Scottsdale
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  var rmap1, mk1;
  var rmap2, mk2;

  function initialize() {
      var coord = new google.maps.LatLng(33.5783309936523, -112.573112487793);
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        center: {
          lat: 33.5783309936523,
          lng: -112.573112487793
        },
        zoom: 8
      });
      //White Tanks   
      var boundaries1 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(32.22935, -114.1923),
        new google.maps.LatLng(34.92731, -110.9539));
      rmap1 = new google.maps.GroundOverlay("https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg", boundaries1);
      rmap1.setMap(map);
      mk1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.57832983, -112.57310897),
        map: map,
        title: '462.550 Mhz at 50 Watts',
        draggable: false,
        zIndex: 1
      });
      //Scottsdale
      var boundaries2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(32.36672, -113.4623),
        new google.maps.LatLng(35.06469, -110.2188));
      rmap2 = new google.maps.GroundOverlay("https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg", boundaries2);
      rmap2.setMap(map);
      mk2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.715703, -111.840549),
        map: map,
        title: '462.600 Mhz at 20 Watts',
        draggable: false,
        zIndex: 1
      });
    }
    //Checkbox Function

  function showcov(m, v) {
    if (v.checked) m.setMap(map);
    else m.setMap(null);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing, thanks I appreciate it! I've been working around the clock on these three projects, 20+ hours a day. I always forget about setting the map as a global.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference of checkbox to `showcov()` like this

```
<input name="ckc1" onclick="showcov(rmap1,this);" type="checkbox" checked="true">White Tanks</input>
<input name="ckc2" onclick="showcov(rmap2,this);" type="checkbox" checked="true">Scottsdale</input>
```

But there is one problem, `setMap(null)` not only removes the groundOverlay but also destroys it so you cannot add them again using `setMap()` that's why when you un-mark and then re-mark again overlay won't appear. To make it work you need to again create a new overlay object and set it on the map using `setMap(map)`

I think a better way would be not to remove but simple hide it using `setOpacity()`.That way you don't need to re-create overlays

```
function showcov(m,v){
    if(v.checked) {
        //m.setMap(map); 
        m.setOpacity(1);
    else {
        //m.setMap(null); 
        m.setOpacity(0);
     }
}
```

On android you may use much easier `setVisible(true)` and `setVisible(false)` but unfortunately those functions are not available for the web version

Comment: I looked at doing that, but I figured this map won't be on a mobile device, AFAIK, but you have some great suggestions which helped me in another issue I was having in regards to a different project - much appreciated!